# Using a while Loop to iterate on an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to used this while loop to iterate over my array to find the smallest number in my array.  Thoughts?

```
array_2=[]
test_scores=[75, 100, 85, 65, 84, 87, 95, 99, 200]


while test_scores.count > 1
  if test_scores[1] > test_scores[0]
    array_2.push(test_scores[0])
    test_scores.count
  elsif
    total_scores[0] < test_scores[1]
      array_2.push(test_scores[1])
      test_scores.count
  elsif 
    test_scores.count==1
    break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use [`Enumerable#min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) ?

```
test_scores = [75, 100, 85, 65, 84, 87, 95, 99, 200]
test_scores.min
# => 65
```

---

`test_scores` is not changed. `test_scores.count > 1` is always `true`. The `while` loop does not end.

And the code compares only the first element (`test_scores[0]`) and the second element (test_scores[1](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min)) only.

Comment: i could but I am still curious to why this is not running...any idea?

Comment: @user2980721, I added a reason why the code does not give you what you want.

Comment: but shouldn't it still break eventually when the test_array==1?

Comment: @user2980721, Do you mean `test_array.count == 1`? `test_array.count` does not change because `test_array` itself does not change.

Comment: @user2980721, Put `p test_array` inside the `while` loop, and run; then, you will get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over complicating the algorithm. Assuming you don't want to use Ruby's Enumerable#min, what is the overall goal? If you're looking for one minimum value then you'll be returning a single variable. You have to check all the values in the array so wouldn't something like the following be easier to follow?

```
minimum_value = nil
test_scores.each {|num| minimum_value = num if minimum_value.nil? or num < minimum_value}
```

Essentially setting minimum_value to nil adds an edge case for if test_scores had no values stored in it. The each is just iterates over each value in test_scores (calling it each member in turn 'num'), then it sets the minimum_value to the first number or any number less than what it currently is.

Comment: How about `minimum_value = test_scores[0]; test_scores.each {|num| minimum_value = num if num < minimum_value}` ?

Comment: I come from a c++ background so it's habit for me to null/nil things out, even though apparently Ruby will auto nil if test_scores is a blank array.